# Removing header and footer when displaying logout page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have added below code in my app.component.html

```
<app-header ></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer ></app-footer>
```

and in my routing file I am using below code

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: Home },
    { path: 'temp', component: TempComponent },
    { path: 'temp2', component: TempComponent2 },
    { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

The problem is when I render logout page the header and footer are still present. Which is in correct as my header has user information also.

Second thing is I have TempComponent and TempComponent1, when it renders I have to show header and footer in each component also.

Is there a solution or should I change my approach? I don't want to copy and past the header and footer in each and every template.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One approach to avoid having header/footer in each page would be to change your routing so you have a another `router-outlet` at the child level.  Something like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { 
      path: '', 
      children: [
        { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'temp', component: TempComponent },
        { path: 'temp2', component: TempComponent2 },
       ]
      component: HomeComponent
    },      
    { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

Then the top-level `app.component.html` template is just `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

And the `home.component` template contains the header and footer elements and the child router outlet.

The point here is that the header/footer are removed from the root template, so they won't appear everywhere.

*Another* possibility is that rather than cutting/pasting header and footer as you put it, you can create a wrapper element for all pages that want the standard header/footer e.g. a `standard-page.component`.

```
<app-header></app-header>
   <ng-content></ng-content>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Then in Home, Temp, Temp2 (not Logout), you can wrap them as 'standard' pages that require header/footer.

E.g. for TempComponent html.

```
<standard-page>
  //TempComponent content here ..
</standard-page>
```

Comment: This is a good approach, after trying it i can see the CSS is gone for a toss.

Comment: any idea how to retain the same CSS

Comment: Excellent! The first approach is cleaner!

Answer (score 6):

You can add a method userIsLogged() in the app root component that returns true if the user is logged in and false if not (your component can use a service to check that). You can then use the structural directive *ngIf to hide the header and footer depending the return value of the method.

```
<app-header *ngIf="userIsLogged()"></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer *ngIf="userIsLogged()></app-footer>
```

Updated Code :

```
    <app-header *ngIf="userIsLogged()"></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-footer *ngIf="userIsLogged()"></app-footer>
```

Comment: And what if I am not logged in and I still want to access some pages, but my header and footer are gone? This is not a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

It's very simple just use ***ngif** in the app-header & app-footer tags

your **app.component.html** code would be like

```
<app-header *ngif="router.url !== '/logout' " ></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer *ngif="router.url !== '/logout' " ></app-footer>
```

Don't forget to add below constructor with router in your **app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {

     constructor(public router: Router){}
}
```

In this way, you don't need to change your approach and you can get what you want!

Comment: *ngIf, not *ngif

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this - is create separate route for *login/logout/register/forget password* pages but if you do not want to change your app structure then you can look out at `NgSwitch` which is switching views on basis of conditions

Answer (score 0):

You should go for common approach-

**app.component.html** contains only:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Other components html will be like:

```
<app-header ></app-header>
<p>aboutus works!</p>
<app-footer ></app-footer>
```

Other components where you don't want header and/or footer remove

```
<app-header ></app-header>
```

and/or

```
<app-footer ></app-footer>
```