# Login form to take place of the root component in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

All inner pages in my application have header, footer and toolbar components.

This is my root component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <app-header></app-header>
    <main id="content">
      <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
    <app-footer></app-footer>`,
}) 
export class AppComponent { ... }
```

Here is the routing table:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard]},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    ...
];
```

When displaying the login form the header, footer and toolbar are displayed. I don't want them visible on the login page. I'd like my `LoginComponent` to replace the `AppComponent` if possible on the login page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972593/removing-header-and-footer-when-displaying-logout-page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing header and footer when displaying logout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972593/removing-header-and-footer-when-displaying-logout-page)

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a similar application. What I have done is route the login page with path: ". Login routes to admin component which acts as a parent component with header, footer and sidebar. This admin component has a main view with a router outlet where I route all the child components with routes like this admin/form1, admin/form2 etc.

Comment: *login button routes to admin component.