# How to remove header and footer from error page in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am trying to remove the header and footer from an error page without removing them from other pages.

My app.components.html file shows the following:

```
<app-navigation></app-navigation>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

My app-routing.module.ts file shows the following:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{path:'',component:HomeComponent},
{path:'CurrencyCalculator',component:CurrencyCalculatorComponent},
{path:'**',component:ErrorPageComponent}
];
```

I tried the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972593/removing-header-and-footer-when-displaying-logout-page), however that did not work. I keep getting error message: Error: src/app/app-routing.module.ts:16:3 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

Here's how it looks when following the approach shown in the link above:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
path: '', 
children: [
{path:'CurrencyCalculator',component:CurrencyCalculatorComponent},
]
component: HomeComponent
},   
{path:'**',component:ErrorPageComponent}   

];
```

Where do I go from here to get it done?

Comment: What do you mean by "VSCode would not take it"? VSCode is just an editor, if there was an error please post it.

Comment: Visual Studio Code ("IDE") would throw an error when trying that approach in the app-routing.module.ts file, therefore I am thinking I need a different approach.

Comment: The error I am getting is:                                                                                                
 Error: src/app/app-routing.module.ts:16:3 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

Comment: Ok, not to be rude but reading the message you're missing a comma on line 16

Comment: That's what I thought at first and I added the "," before  component: HomeComponent. After that I no longer got an error message, however I still keep getting the header and footer in all my pages. My main objective is not show them in the error page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routed components get displayed where the `<router-outlet>` directive is located, which means that any routed component will have a `<app-navigation></app-navigation>` and a `<app-footer></app-footer>` around it.

If you want to change that behavior, your `app.component.html` could be just:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And then you would use child routes to handle two scenarios:

1. Display the `ErrorComponent` by default as you do now
2. Any other use case would display a `DefaultLayoutComponent` that has a template similar to the one you currently use in `app.component.html`

And this `DefaultLayoutComponent` would have a child route config to handle all possible components to display in this secondary router outlet.

Comment: So, pretty much I will have to add the header and footer in all pages, except the error page rather then having a template as the templates cannot be overridden in specific pages? that works but it forces me to add those elements (header and footer everywhere). Is that the only way it can be done?

Comment: No. You would have another container component (the one I call DefaultLayoutComponent) that has the header and footer, and that's it. Nothing is duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have fixed the issue with the missing comma. You will want to change your app.components.html to

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And your HomeComponent to

```
<app-navigation></app-navigation>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

This way the router outlet in home component will take over for children of that so the navigation and footer components will only show for those.

Here is quick example on stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-sidenav-generate-nav-n3ioof?file=src/app/app.module.ts